# Why is my Python parallel process running too many times?

Tags: python, function, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, pool

I've written a function that carries out a stochastic simulation on a system of chemical reactions.

```
def gillespie_tau_leaping(start_state, LHS, stoch_rate, state_change_array): # inputs are a series of arrays
    t = SimulationTimer()
    t.start()
    #update molecule numbers for each species in model
    #update current time of the system 
    t.stop()
    print(f"Accumulated time: {t.get_accumulated_time():0.10f} seconds")
return popul_num_all, tao_all, t.get_accumulated_time() # popul_num_all is an array of changing molecule numbers over time, tao_all is the evolution of time throughout the simulation

popul_num_all, tao_all, accumulated_elapsed_time = gillespie_tau_leaping(start_state, LHS, stoch_rate, state_change_array)  # Call the function to make variables accessible for plotting.
```

I've now written the following code to run the `gillespie_tau_leaping` function multiple times using pythons `multiprocessing` `pool` class.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool() as p:
        pool_results = p.starmap(gillespie_tau_leaping, [(start_state, LHS, stoch_rate, state_change_array) for i in range(4)])
        p.close()
        p.join()   
        total_time = 0.0
        for tuple_results in pool_results:
            total_time += tuple_results[2]
    print(f"Total time:\n{total_time}") 


def gillespie_plot(tao_all, popul_num):
    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
    ax1.plot(tao_all, popul_num_all[:, 0], label='S', color= 'Green')
    ax1.legend()
    for i, label in enumerate(['T', 'U']):
        ax2.plot(tao_all, popul_num_all[:, i+1], label=label)
    ax2.legend()
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
    return fig

gillespie_plot(tao_all, popul_num_all)
```

`gillespie_plot`, plots the results of changing molecule numbers, `popul_num_all`, over time, `tao_all`.

Only when I run this code it simulates `gillespie_tau_leaping` 9 times. The first time is because I make a call to the function, to make some variables accessible. Its the next 8 simulations I don't understand, the first 4 simulate the system and plot the graphs but don't return `total_time` of the parallel simulations. The second 4 simulations don't plot the graphs but do return the `total_time` of the parallel simulations.

I'm only expecting/wanting 4 simulations after the function call, which plot the graphs and return `total_time`

What am I doing wrong?

Cheers

Comment: You have to safe-guard the `gillespie_plot` call at the bottom with `if __name__ == '__main__':` like the upper code block.

Comment: Do I add it just above the function call?

Comment: Does all that code appear in a single file? And is the first line after the return statement of `gillespie_tau_leaping()` meant to be in the module scope? Secondly, what is the size of tao_all and popul_num_all? How many items do they have? 1000s? Millions? Billions? That effects the best way to solve this.

Comment: All the code is in the same file yes, that first line after `gillespie_tau_leaping` is meant to put the returns in the global environment for some reason the `gillespie_plot` function can't reach them otherwise, In this model both `popul_num_all` and `tao_all` are in the 100s, but in some other models they can be 100,000 if possible I'd like a fairly universal solution where their length is concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The breakdown of your program is as follows:

1. On startup the main process defines `gillespie_tau_leaping()` and then calls it as `popul_num_all, tao_all, accumulated_elapsed_time = gillespie_tau_leaping(start_state, LHS, stoch_rate, state_change_array)`
2. The main process  evaluates `__name__ == '__main__'` as true and so starts the multiprocessing pool and repeats the following steps 4 times

   1. The subprocess loads up and then defines and calls `gillespie_tau_leaping()` (as is in the other step 1)
   2. The subprocess evaluates `__name__ == '__main__'` as false and does not create a new pool.
   3. The subprocess then defines and calls `gillespie_plot()` with the arguments from  step 2.1
   4. The subprocess receives the request to call `gillespie_tau_leaping()` that comes from the `starmap` call and processes it, returning the result.
3. The main process receives the results of the starmap invocation (2.4) and prints out the time result
4. The main process defines and calls `gillespie_plot()` with the arguments from step 1

To run your code only 4 times you should do:

```
def gillespie_tau_leaping(start_state, LHS, stoch_rate, state_change_array):
    ...

def gillespie_plot(tao_all, popul_num):
    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
    ax1.plot(tao_all, popul_num_all[:, 0], label='S', color= 'Green')
    ax1.legend()
    for i, label in enumerate(['T', 'U']):
        ax2.plot(tao_all, popul_num_all[:, i+1], label=label)
    ax2.legend()
    plt.tight_layout()
    # plt.show() # this can block
    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool() as p:
        pool_results = p.starmap(gillespie_tau_leaping, [(start_state, LHS, stoch_rate, state_change_array) for i in range(4)])
        # pool is implicitly closed and joined at the end of the with block. 
    
    total_time = 0.0
    for tuple_results in pool_results:
        total_time += tuple_results[2]
    print(f"Total time:\n{total_time}")

    for tao_all, popul_num_all, _total_time in pool_results:
        gillespie_plot(tao_all, popul_num_all)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run the code in a subprocess, the module (file) is going to be executed again. The `if __name__ == '__main__':` works as a safe-guard to prevent certain code from running.

In your case `gillespie_plot(tao_all, popul_num_all)` is unprotected and will run code in every subprocess that should be run only once.

Add the same `if` condition as for the upper code block to prevent that:

```
[…]
if __name__ == '__main__':
    gillespie_plot(tao_all, popul_num_all)
```

Comment: I've done this but it's still running 9 times? should I put the if condition in the `gillespie_plot` function?

Comment: You have to protect the call (`popul_num_all, tao_all, accumulated_elapsed_time = gillespie_tau_leaping(…)`) as well, not the function of it's results. Remember that the condition will only work if placed in the file you are originally executing.